# Changing default connection string for Membership, Roles, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

By default, it seems like my web application is using `LocalSqlServer` as the connection string to use for any application services such as Membership/Roles/Authentication/etc.

Is there any way I can change what the default connection string should be? It seems so arbitrary that the default is "LocalSqlServer" and the only way I was able to find this was by googling for this for about two hours.

I don't want to be forced to have to name my server connection "LocalSqlServer" and I have no idea if this is a preexisting item that I might be overwriting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these connection strings can be set in web.config:

**Membership**

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
      <add 
        name="SqlMembershipProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
        connectionStringName="MyMembershipConnectionString"
       />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**Roles**

```
<roleManager defaultProvider ="SqlRoleProvider" >
   <providers>
     <add
       name="SqlRoleProvider" 
       type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
       connectionStringName="MyRolesConnectionString"
     />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

See here for more info: [How to: Use the ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

2 things.
Look for, or add a  "connectionStringName" property in your membership config.

Here is an example that uses it

```
<system.web>
 ...
 <membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="MembershipADProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, 
            Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                connectionStringName="YOUR CONN STRING" 
                connectionUsername="<domainName>\administrator" 
                connectionPassword="password"/>
   </providers>
 </membership>
 ...
</system.web>
```

And you need to setup the conn sting of course

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="YOUR CONN STRING" 
   connectionString=
    "[ANY ConnectionSTRIN]" />
</connectionStrings>
```